# How do I rotate ephemeral IP on Google Cloud Compute Engine instance?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Is there a way to change the external IP of a Compute Engine instance periodically?

I have a Compute Engine Group that I scale down to 0 and then back to whatever number I need to refresh ephemeral external IPs. Is there a better way?

Comment: The ephemeral IP address is managed by Google Cloud DHCP. AFAIK there are no interfaces/APIs for you to manage this for your GCE instances. The only method that I know of is to terminate the instance and recreate. This is what your MIG (Managed Instance Group) is doing for you when you scale.

Comment: Note: since you are using a MIG, you can add an instance and terminate another instance using APIs. This might get you where you want.

Comment: Just as a mostly idle question, what are you looking to accomplish by changing an instance's external IP?

Answer (score 1):

```
gcloud compute instance-groups managed recreate-instances <group_name> --instances=<instance_id> --zone=<instance_zone>
```